# Wrong dimensions when normalizing an image

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix, sobel

I am getting some error in this code section

```
 X=imread ('Lighthouse.jpg'); %reads picture as int8 matrix  
figure, imagesc(X), colormap gray, title('original picture'), % display picture  
filter=[-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1]; % builds Sobel filter matrix  
filter=single(filter); %convert double to single 
x=single(X); % convert int8 to single  
x=x/max(max(x)); %normalisation to [0,1]
```

The error I get:

```
Error using  / 
Inputs must be 2-D, or at least one input must be scalar.
To compute elementwise RDIVIDE, use RDIVIDE (./) instead.
Error in sobel (line 10)
x=x/max(max(x)); %normalisation to [0,1]
```

---

Also when I am using `./` as suggested, I get new error:

```
Array dimensions must match for binary array op.
Error in sobel (line 10)
x=x./max(max(x)); %normalisation to [0,1]
```

I am doing something wrong in the normalization step.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Looking at the past questions of you: please do not include the tag in the title, that's what the tagging system is for. Please see [this answer on meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/325771).

Answer (score 2):

Why do you call max twice. If I run the code with

```
x=x/max(x(:))
```

I do not get an error. This runs the matrix in 1D.

Comment: calling max twice allows normalization of each layer separately. your line does something else

Answer (score 2):

Whilst [Caduceus' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50209099/5211833) is correct; it normalises over all three colours in one go. What's probably better for your case is [`rgb2gray`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rgb2gray.html), to get a single colour channel and then normalise that instead (using `x/max(x(:))`).

```
X=imread ('lighthouse.png'); %reads picture as int8 matrix  
filter=[-1 0 1; -2 0 2; -1 0 1]; % builds Sobel filter matrix  
filter=single(filter); %convert double to single 
x = single(rgb2gray(X)); % rgb2gray gives a uint8, you want single
% x=x/max(x(:)); %normalisation to [0,1] , not needed here as x can directly be used
% for Sobel purposes as it's a grey scale image.

figure;
subplot(1,2,1)
imagesc(X)
colormap(gray)
title('original picture'), % display picture 
subplot(1,2,2)
imagesc(x)
colormap(gray)
title 'Grey scale'
```

[image]

---

The reason for the first error is is that `max` gives a column-wise maximum, and that this is a 3D matrix. `max(max())` thus gives a 1D one, instead of the desired scalar.

Then the second error occurs because `max(max())` gives an array, which doesn't have the same amount of entries as the full matrix (obviously).

Basically if `size(x) = [row, column channels]`, `size(max(x)) = [row channels]` 
and `size(max(max(x)) = [row]`. Using the colon operator actually makes the entire 3D matrix a single column vector, and `max(x(:))` thus gives a single value, which is the maximum across all rows, columns and channels.

Answer (score -2):

When I run your code the error message says "Use RDIVIDE (./)". 
implement it like this:

```
x=x./max(max(x));
```

This divides each RGB layer by its maximum. You may have to replicate the max values (I guess this depends on matlab version), use this line instead

```
x=x./repmat(max(max(x)),size(X,1),size(X,2),1);
```

Comment: To quote the OP: *Also when I am using ./ as suggested, I get new error: *Array dimensions must match for binary array op. Error in sobel (line 10) x=x./max(max(x)); %normalisation to [0,1]* So no, that doesn't work. See my comment on the question as to why that is.